# Simple templated function to convert std::vectors - "illegal use of this type as an expression"

Tags: c++, templates, std

I wrote a quick method to convert std::vectors from one type to another:

```
template<class A, class B>
vector<B> ConvertSTDVector_AToB(vector<A> vector)
{
    vector<B> converted_vector;

    for(unsigned int i= 0; i< vector.size(); i++)
        converted_vector.push_back(vector[i]);

    return converted_vector;
}
```

But the compiler errors with "error C2275: 'B' : illegal use of this type as an expression" on the line after the opening bracket. At first I thought somehow 'B' was defined elsewhere, but changing both template type names results in the same error. Then I thought that something strange was going on with the types. But even making both template parameters ints doesn't change anything.

I can't for the life of me see what's wrong with this method. (Although I feel like I might just be blind to something obvious, at this point).

Comment: This redefines the meaning of `vector`: `vector<A> vector`. Instead of naming a type, it names a function parameter. Replace with `vector<A> v`, and the code should compile ([demo](http://ideone.com/WeCEHE)).

Comment: So you're intentionally reinventing [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig or `std::copy` :).

Comment: @WhozCraig More like `std::copy` without explicit conversion?

Comment: @pmr I think half the standard lib algorithms could be tooled to do this, now that a I think about it more. I like Brian's =P

Comment: @WhozCraig We should have a contest to come up with the most perverted way to do it. My entry will be using `std::accumulate`.

Comment: I should use the existing solutions, I admit, but when I'm trying to work quickly I tend to just whip up my own solutions if it is something I consider trivial. Thanks for the tips though, everyone.

Comment: `auto converted = std::vector<B>(vectorA.begin(), vectorA.end());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply rename the parameter name. Its name hides the std::vector name.

Or write the erroneous line the following way

```
class vector<B> converted_vector;
```

that is use the elaborated type name for std::vector that to distinguish it from object (parameter) vector.

The code of the function can be written in different ways. For example

```
template<class A, class B>
vector<B> ConvertSTDVector_AToB(vector<A> vector)
{
    class vector<B> converted_vector( vector.begin(), vector.end() );

    return converted_vector;
}
```

pr

```
template<class A, class B>
vector<B> ConvertSTDVector_AToB(vector<A> vector)
{
    class vector<B> converted_vector;

    converted_vector.assign( vector.begin(), vector.end() );
    return converted_vector;
}
```

ans so on.

Comment: +1. I'm quietly suggesting the template parameter order be reversed to allow partial deduction of `A` without having to specify it with the invoke. I.e. `auto dst = ConvertSTDVector_AToB<DstType>(src);` should be plausible without forcing the caller to specify `<SrcType,DstType>` in the template param list. Nice answer, btw.

Comment: Ah! I knew it would be somthing simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to do such a function, instead all you have to do is to use `std::copy` provided that the objects you want to convert are convertible to each other by providing an overloaded conversion operator. Just like the example below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class B;

class A {
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, A const &a);
  int id;
public:
  A() : id(0) { }
  A(int const _id) : id(_id) { }
  operator B() const; 
};

class B {
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, B const &b);
  int id;
public:
  B() : id(0) { }
  B(int const _id) : id(_id) { }
  operator A() const { return A(id); }
};

A::operator B() const { return B(id); }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, A const &a) { return (out << a.id); }
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, B const &b) { return (out << b.id); }

int main() {
  std::vector<B> bv{B(1), B(2), B(3), B(4), B(5)};
  std::vector<A> av(bv.size());
  std::vector<B> bbv(bv.size());
  std::copy(bv.begin(), bv.end(), av.begin());
  for(auto i : av) std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::copy(av.begin(), av.end(), bbv.begin());
  for(auto i : bbv) std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;  
  return 0;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7f1d204088e4eff)