# Illegal use of this type as an expression when calling template class member

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, templates, visual-studio-2008

I have a problem with the usage of a static class member `size` of a class `SizeObj`, which is used as template parameter for a template class `SizeTemplate`. See below the code snippet, which I reduced to the minimum.

In fact that code below ran well up to MS VS2008, but now the compilation fails 
when compiling with VS2010. The following error messages are displayed:

```
error C2275: 'K' : illegal use of this type as an expression
error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union
```

It need to be said, that the compilation fails only, if the `getSize` method is
called at least once.

Please don't ask about the sense of the code below, as said I reduced it to the
essential minimum to explain. However, I need to admit that the 
usage of the member 'size' is not very elegant due to several reasons, and maybe
there are lots of better solutions, but at the moment, I don't have any choice
to keep it like that.

Do you know what may be wrong here? Is it possible to solve that by build
settings or something similar? I didn't find yet anything suitable yet.

In the following posts it was easy, because an instance of class K is available, but for my problem, I don't know how to get that instance properly:

- [Illegal use of type in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479842/illegal-use-of-type-in-template)
- [Simple templated function to convert std::vectors - "illegal use of this type as an expression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292895/simple-templated-function-to-convert-stdvectors-illegal-use-of-this-type-as)

```
//myTemplate.h
```

class SizeObj
{
public:
    static const int size = 1;
};

template<class K>
class SizeTemplate
{
public:
    int getSize();
};

template<class K>
int SizeTemplate<K>::getSize()
{
    return K.size;
}

//main.cpp

int main(...)
{
    SizeTemplate<SizeObj> sizeObj;
    printf("size:%d", sizeObj.getSize());
}

Thank you a lot in advance!

tangoal

Comment: Try `K::size` instead.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Was faster than expected though. Instead of K.size, it needs to be K::size, which is clear. In fact, this means that the previous compiler wasn't that compliant with the C++ specification.

Comment: Thanks songyuanyao!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Java, in C++ you cannot use the dot operator on classes, you need use the scope resolution operator (i.e. `::`) to get things from within the class scope (for example the `size` static variable), so replace `return K.size` with  `return K::size`

Also marking the method to be `constexpr` is likely going to help here.